# ReactJS Modal Window onClick

Tags: reactjs

My ReactJS Modal Window do not work.

Here is code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Modal.css';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

const Modal = ({ handleClose, show, children }) => {

const showHideClassName = show ? "modal display-block" : "modal display-none";

return (
<div className={showHideClassName}>
  <section className="card modal-main">
    {children}
    <div className="clear"></div>
    <Button onClick={handleClose}>
      Close
    </Button>
  </section>
</div>
);
};

export default Modal;
```

And here is code in my component:

```
function modalState(state) {
  return state;
};

<Modal show={modalState(setModal)} handleClose={modalState(false)}>
  {
    <div></div>
  }
</Modal>
```

And if I click Add user button then nothing happens:

```
  <Button variant="primary" size="sm" onClick={() => {
                      setModal = true;
                      modalState(setModal);
                    }}>Add User</Button>{' '}
```

What should I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use useState hook.

Your Modal component.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './Modal.css';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

const Modal = ({ show, children }) => {
  const [modalState, setModalState] = useState(show);
  const showHideClassName = show ? "modal display-block" : "modal display-none";

  return (
    <div className={showHideClassName}>
      <section className="card modal-main">
        {children}
        <div className="clear"></div>
        <Button onClick={() => setModalState(false)}>
          Close
        </Button>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

And your component where calls Modal component.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Modal from './path/Modal';

const CustomComponent = () => {
  const [modalState, setModalState] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <Modal show={modalState}>
        {
          <div></div>
        }
      </Modal>

      <Button
        variant="primary" size="sm"
        onClick={() => setModalState(true)}
      >
        Add User
      </Button>
    </>
  );
}

export default CustomComponent;
```

But please note that this would be just a temporary solution based on your current codes. If you want a better and permanent solution, I'd like to recommend to implement the global state management thru your whole codebase using Redux or Recoil.

Comment: I get this error with our code: TypeError: setModalState is not a function

Comment: Seems like you have to change `<Modal show={modalState} handleClose={setModalState(false)}>` to `<Modal show={modalState} handleClose={() => setModalState(false)}>`

Comment: Still not work.

Comment: Does it give any errors?

Comment: TypeError: setModalState is not a function

Comment: updated the codes on my post

Answer (score 0):

In the onclick event useState set is not done to set the value of the Modal

```
   setModal({modal:true})
```

And

```
<Modal show={modal} handleClose={modalState(false)}>
  {
      <div></div>
  }
 </Modal>
```

Comment: I get this error:  ./src/components/ManageAdmin/ManageUsers.js
  Line 53:15:  'modal' is not defined  no-undef

Answer (score 0):

I think if you do this it will work.

```js
const [isVisibleModal, setVisibleModal] = useState(false); // <- add

function closeModal() {
  setVisibleModal(!isVisibleModal);
};

<Modal show={isVisibleModal} handleClose={closeModal}>
  {
    <div></div>
  }
</Modal>
```

```js
<Button 
  variant="primary" 
  size="sm" 
  onClick={() => setVisibleModal(true)}
>
 Add User
</Button>
```

Hope this helps you!

You should use setVisibleModal function same page like this code

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [isVisibleModal, setVisibleModal] = useState(false); // <- add

  function closeModal() {
    setVisibleModal(!isVisibleModal);
  };

  return (
   <>
    <Modal show={isVisibleModal} handleClose={closeModal}>
     {
       <div></div>
     }
    </Modal>

    <Button 
      variant="primary" 
      size="sm" 
      onClick={() => setVisibleModal(true)}
    >
     Add User
    </Button>
   </>
  )
}

export default YourComponent;
```

Comment: I get error of setVisibleModal s not function.

Comment: The function must be called in the part where setVisible Modal is declared.
You should use "setVisibleModal" on the same page with  This  "const [isVisibleModal, setVisibleModal] = useState(false);"

Comment: Please check the updated code.